# How to export a variable to two others scirpts in bash in separate calls

Tags: bash

So we have a situation where we are required to pass a unique random number to two other scripts.

We run these scripts one after the other something like this

```
/tmp/XSRF.sh --cookie-number $cookie-number
/tmp/cookie_value.sh --cookie-number $cookie-number
```

and these calls need to be separate and we can't combine them, as it would break authentication with the client application.

I was thinking of making three scripts call like this

```
/tmp/cookie_number.sh
/tmp/XSRF.sh --cookie-number $cookie-number
/tmp/cookie_value.sh --cookie-number $cookie-number
```

With the first `cookie_number.sh` script exporting that cookie-number variable to be consumed by the other two scripts.

Remember all three script calls will be separate, one after the other.

Calling and called are Java spring-boot apps with rabbitmq being the message-broker between them.
The called java spring-boot app will do the actual shell script job.

So how can we achieve this scenario first in bash?

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit confusing: A script can not **export** something. You could have `cookie_number.sh` write the cookie number to stdout and catch the stdout in your main script; or you can write cookie_number.sh in a way that it does not need to be run in a child process. Both approaches have their advantage and disadvantage; I would most likely go with the former, as it provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can either `source` the first script (`source ./your_script` or `. ./your_script`) and have it set the variable; or you can use command substitution. I would recommend the latter, since it makes it explicit how the current context is affected:

```
cookie="$(/tmp/cookie_number.sh)"
/tmp/XSRF.sh --cookie-number "$cookie-number"
/tmp/cookie_value.sh --cookie-number "$cookie-number"
```

PS [*Always* quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) when expanding them to prevent any unintentional effects.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> we can't combine them, as it would break authentication with the
> client application.

It's not clear what you mean by "combine" in that context but I'm going to assume it means you can't put all of the code from both scripts into one file and in particular it does NOT mean you can't call both scripts from a wrapper function (or script if you prefer) in which case:

```
cookie-monster() {
    /tmp/XSRF.sh --cookie-number "$@"
    /tmp/cookie_value.sh --cookie-number "$@"
}
...
cookie-monster "$cookie_number"
```

or:

```
cookie-monster() {
    local cookie_number
    cookie_number=however you figure it out
    /tmp/XSRF.sh --cookie-number "$cookie_number"
    /tmp/cookie_value.sh --cookie-number "$cookie_number"
}
...
cookie-monster
```

Shell variables cannot contain `-`s so I changed the `-` to `_` in `cookie_number` and they must be quoted unless you have a specific reason to remove the quotes, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Can't combine scripts as our java spring-boot app is treating everything that is outputted either through a single script(Both scripts' code added into one) or one script calling another script as one complete string and this is causing authentication failure with client application. Our code treats the output of the first script as a token and the output of the second script as cookie header values. Both script output needs to be separate calls producing separate strings.

Comment: If we can't do anything with bash scripts to make that unique random number available to other two scripts(XSRF.sh and cookie_value.sh) in separate script calls between two services then I guess code changes will have to be made to mitigate something.

Comment: I've no idea what a "java spring-boot app" is, nor do I understand your description of why what I show wouldn't work for you as I see nothing in those descriptions that would preclude doing what I show. Maybe it's something to do with "between two services" which you just mentioned in a comment? Anyway, you asked how to do this in bash and got 2 answers so far that show how to do this in bash so if neither of those is what you need then please edit your question to clarify your needs, including describing exactly what would make the current answers not work for you.